# Rails Bootstrap CSS Problems

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a few issues with trying to customize Twitter Bootstrap for my rails app.

1) When you type in the search box the text seems to resize down slightly which gives it a weird stretching effect:

[image: Search Bar Form]

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
   <input type="text" class="search-query span2">
   <div class="icon-search"></div>
 </form>

.navbar-search {
  .input-prepend {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .search-query {
    padding-left: 29px;
    background-color: hsl(360, 0%, 17%) !important;
  }
  .icon-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 11px;
    background-image: url("http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
  }
  .search-query:focus, .search-query.focused {
    color: $white;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

To get a better idea, here's another photo with the focused text color changed to gray:*

[image]

---

2) When resizing the navbar, it apparently doesn't keep the navbar attached to the right side of the screen:

[image: Nav Bar Resize]

```
<header class="navbar center">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to image_tag("logo.png", size: "275x275", border: 0, alt: "logo"), root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <%= link_to "New Post", newpost_path, class: "btn btn-custom" %>
          <%= link_to "Browse Posts", posts_path, class: "btn btn-custom" %>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <% if signed_in? %>
              <li class="active"><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
              <li id="fat-menu" class="active dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <b class="caret">Account </b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
              </li>
            <% else %>
              <li class="active"><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
            <input type="text" class="search-query span2">
            <div class="icon-search"></div>
          </form>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>

.navbar-inner {
  background-color: $yellow;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: none;
}
```

I Tried Cobaco's suggestions and here are the results (still have problems, left side touches the browser, right side has a gutter space and the bar is still being squeezed.):

[image: Resizing]

**Edit: The table-row and table-cell suggestion worked, however I had to make some modifications to the background and the left side still isn't flush.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for queston 1):

try using css2.1 table display:

```
.home-row {display: table-row;}
.home-row>.span4 {display: table-cell;}
```

see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html for more on that
browsersupport for CSS Table Display is good these days (see http://caniuse.com/css-table  only IE7 and below don't support that)

for 3)

```
.navbar {position: relative; right: 0;}
```

should keep it attached to the right-side

Comment: I tried this, it does even out the left side but match up with the footer but it's pushing the third column below the first one and changing the "border-radius" for the home-row now longer rounds the edges of the box.

Comment: adding an additional "width: 33%;" to the .home-row>.span4 should ensure the 3 boxes are kept next to each other

Comment: Still no luck with either of those. Adding the width doesn't stop it from dropping the third box. Also the navbar isn't fixed and I noticed that when you resize the browser smaller than the main content the left side is attached to the left side of the browser with zero gutter room and the right side still has the gap.

Comment: See the "Edit 2" at the bottom of the post for screenshots of it.

Comment: Actually looks like I was able to solve question 1 by adding the background to the cells instead of the row and changing the width to 30%. Thanks!